# How to access each column of the array and perform average calculation on each column in C programming?

Tags: arrays, c

I have written a user-defined function in C. Here is my code:

```
void percentage(float* array, int* carbohydrate_avg, int* protein_avg, int* fat_avg){
    
double sum = 0;
    
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        
        *(array+3*i+0)= *(array+3*i+0)*100/300;
        *(array+3*i+1)= *(array+3*i+1)*(100/50);    
        *(array+3*i+2)= *(array+3*i+2)*(100/65);
    
        *carbohydrate_avg = array[i]/SIZE;
        *protein_avg = (*(array+3*i+1))/SIZE;
        *fat_avg = (*(array+3*i+2))/SIZE;
    }
    
}
```

There are three columns here and I wish to calculate the average by finding the sum of each column and dividing over the number of rows. How should I amend my code because I have no clue to access each column of the array? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the array to your function with a pointer, you could possibly pass the array with dimensional qualifications.  Following is a sample program utilizing your variable definitions that might point you in the direction you want to go.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 5

void percentage(float array[SIZE][3], float* carbohydrate_avg, float* protein_avg, float* fat_avg)
{
    *carbohydrate_avg = 0;  /* Initialize the avarage work fields */
    *protein_avg = 0;
    *fat_avg = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {

        *carbohydrate_avg += array[i][0] * 100.0 / 300.0;
        *protein_avg += array[i][1] * 100.0 / 50.0;
        *fat_avg += array[i][2] * 100.0 / 65.0;
    }

    *carbohydrate_avg = *carbohydrate_avg / (float)SIZE;
    *protein_avg = *protein_avg / (float) SIZE;
    *fat_avg = *fat_avg / (float) SIZE;
}

int main()
{
    float carbs, protein, fat;

    float arr[SIZE][3] =
    {
        {1800.0, 15.0, 10.0},
        {1700.0, 18.0, 11.0},
        {2200.0, 21.0, 14.0},
        {1577.0, 25.0, 17.0},
        {1144.0, 12.0, 16.0},
    };

    percentage(arr, &carbs, &protein, &fat);

    printf("Average carbohydrates: %f, Average protein: %f, Average fat: %f\n", carbs, protein, fat);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, since the function wants to segregate the array into a specific number of rows and three columns, the array parameter is defined as a two-dimensional array with the number of rows being a predefined value and the columns being the second array index with a value of three.

In the "main" function, I just set up a simple set of five groups of values in order to run the program.

FYI, since your averages probably would contain fractions, I changed them to be float variables.

Hopefully, this will provide you with some ideas for passing an array as a parameter.  It is but just another way of passing array data.

Regards.